# Windows decrypting TC volume without passphrase?

Tags: windows, truecrypt, passphrase, cache

I remember having read a blog post or a forum post, some years ago, about a TrueCrypt user whose Windows machine sometimes, at boot, did not ask for the TC passphrase and decrypted automatically the volume.

It turned out Windows, in some circumstances, cached the passphrase.  Obviously this is an enormous vulnerability.  It was solved by deactivating some Windows cache, IIRC.

Does anyone have the reference for that?

Comment: you mean this: https://superuser.com/a/667061/128626 ?

Comment: No.  It's an issue of Windows storing the passphrase somewhere that survives shutdown.  I have clarified the post.